# Adding New Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Can we please add tags, such as `one-direction`, `harry-styles`, `liam-payne`, `niall-horan`, `louis-tomlinson`, `zayn`, `collaborations`, `2010's`, `Noughties`, `90's`, `80's`, `70's`, `60's`, etc.

##### **WILL BE UPDATED WHEN I THINK OF MORE**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to add tags like that, but in general tags are not created before they are needed. In this case, I don't think we have any content that needs those tags besides maybe `collaborations`. I also suggest maybe asking a question or two that would use one of those tags then a user with the rep can make those tags.

More info can be found here:
[When should I create a new tag? How do I request a new tag if I don't have enough rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/when-should-i-create-a-new-tag-how-do-i-request-a-new-tag-if-i-dont-have-enoug)